# How do I redirect an address to another docker container using the nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, redirect, nginx-config, docker-network

Im trying to redirect to docker containers using nginx but when accessing my server from an 'external pc'(host and other vagrant machines) the address doesn't resolve. I have passed 'host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1' to the containers host file but still no success. Im testing this using vagrant. The server is running Ubuntu Server 21.10 and curling the address from here works.

default nginx conf:

```
server {
listen       80;
listen  [::]:80;
server_name  localhost;
    
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
location /dockercontainer_1 {
    return 301 http://host.docker.internal:79;
}

location /dockercontainer_2 {
    return 301 http://host.docker.internal:34;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
}
```

nginx container host file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.0.1      host.docker.internal
172.17.0.4      35fced58d2eb
```

Ubuntu Server hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 vagrant
127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Answer (score 0):

to access containers from external machine you need to tell nginx to serve on your public `ip` address so just edit the forth line of default nginx config file :

this line:

```
  server_name localhost;
```

To this:

```
  server_name 127.0.0.1  localhost;
```

change `127.0.0.1` to the public ip address of your machine.

Comment: This didnt work for me, I also tried omitting the local host and only supplying the public address as well.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you initiate 2 nginx container with the following command

```
docker container run -d --name dockercontainer1 -p 8081:80 nginx
docker container run -d --name dockercontainer2 -p 8082:80 nginx
```

Then you should edit your localtion block in the host machine

```
location /dockercontainer_1 {
    return 301 http://localhost:8081;
}

location /dockercontainer_2 {
    return 301 http://localhost:8082;
}
```